# cakephp link outside form which access form input values

Tags: forms, cakephp

I have this form with a date input.

```php
echo $this->Form->create('Nodata');
echo $this->Form->input('date1', array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'From:'));
echo $this->Form->input('date2', array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'To:'));
echo $this->Form->end('Get Hours');
```

When the form is submitted, I'm showing the results in the same view, below the form.

My problem is I have a link that is not part of the form and need to read the value (in the view) from the date field on the form to use it as a param
on this link.

```html
// date1 is the param I need to take the value from date input
<th> <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Agents Detail'), array('controller' => 'qcas', 'action' => 'hours', 'paramProject' => $hour['Qca']['dir_id'], 'date1' => $this->data)); ?> </th>
```

Note this link is outside the form and I need a way to read a input on the form to use as param in my link.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly. You didn't specify whether the link need to get date1 after the form is submitted or before the form is submitted (real time). In case of later, have you considered using javascript/jquery? In case of former, you can set the date1 value in a variable (in controller) and pass on to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just using `$this->data` for your `date1` element, you need to refer the field in the `$this->data` object.

CakePHP < 2.0

```
'date1' => $this->data['Nodata']['date1']
```

CakePHP 2.0+

```
'date1' => $this->request->data['Nodata']['date1']
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do at the destination link, but you may need to format the date as well:

```
'date1' => date('Y-m-d', $this->request->data['Nodata']['date1']) // you may need strtotime
```

Comment: Great ! This did it for me: `$this->data['Nodata']['date1'];` In my view itself I formatted the date as follows                    `$origDate1 = $this->data['Nodata']['date1'];
                    $year = $origDate1['year'];
                    $month = $origDate1['month'];
                    $day = $origDate1['day'];
                    $paramDate1 = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;` Thank you !